# Browser-sync in mobile while local development

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

How can I view my local dev website in my phone using gulp Browser-sync? 
I type localhost:3000 in my phones browser but it won't load

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you run gulp in your terminal you should see :

```
    [BS] Access URLs:
 --------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://192.168.10.81:3000
 --------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://192.168.10.81:3001
```

What it means is that your local URL is localhost at port 3000.
For external users it will be the external IP [ not the UI one ]. To access from your phone you need to enter the External IP along with its port in your phone's browser.

You can view all your browser-sync settings by visiting the UI IP.

**Note : For the external link to work on your phone, your phone and computer should be on the same Wi-Fi Network, only then it will work.**

Comment: I have moved on to webpack and it has a flag for https. @AndrewSchultz

Answer (score 9):

I know this is old, but the above option didn't work for me, and I'm running windows 10. I eventually found a solution using the `tunnel` option which is completely hassle-free.

For instance, setting as an option **tunnel: true** will generate a random public URL each time you run BrowserSync: e.g. `http://randomstring23232.localtunnel.me`

However, you can set a preferred tunnel name by passing it as a string to the tunnel option, i.e.
**tunnel: 'preferredtunnelname'**,
which will reproduce: `https://preferredtunnelname.localtunnel.me`

References here: https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/390 and
https://browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-tunnel

Comment: Tunnel was needed to access it on my Android phone. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Kwesi for sharing above. In my case, setting **tunnel:true** alone didn't work until I also added **online:true**. Here's my sample code - worked fine on both computer and mobile device.

```
browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: "app"
    },
    online: true,
    tunnel: true,
    logLevel: "debug"
  });
```