# Browsersync with Gulp - No External URL Showing

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

I'm running Browsersync with Gulp and recently did a system update (moved to Windows 10). Before the update I would see an external URL in the console near the end of Gulp initialization messages. With this URL I could view the website on other devices on my network. After the update the external URL is not listed, even though it's working (I can go to the external URL previously listed on any device on the network). Sometimes these URLs change and I currently have no way of finding the external URL or why it stopped showing in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have the browser-sync 'online' option set to true. And the 'logLevel' set to 'info' or 'debug'.

Comment: thanks, tested this but it still didn't work until I set the option tunnel which I got from another post:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34739846/browser-sync-in-mobile-while-local-development